# Can not update my config file in ASP.net in 64 bit OS ,but works fine in 32 bit

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Windows service which continuously reads the config file. The UI is a form application and it updates the config file. It works on 32 bit systems. In case of 64 bit, it shows the following error when I try to update the config file. In my log file it shows the following Exception.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to save config to file 'C:\Program Files\Essel SWolutions\AutomatedBackUpSetUp2\AutomatedBackUp_Form 1.0.0.exe.Config'.
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.ReplaceFile(String Source, String Target)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   at AutomatedBackUp_Form_1._0._0.configuration.configure(String sourcePathValue, String destinationPathValue, Boolean zipValue, Boolean encryptValue, Boolean mailValue, String frequency, String hour, String minute, String ampm, String time, String sendersid, String recieversid, Boolean txtCheck, Boolean jpgCheck, Boolean zipCheck, Boolean xmlCheck)
   at AutomatedBackUp_Form_1._0._0.ConfigurationForm.updateButton_Click_2(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Does the conf exists? Do you have system privileges to edit a file that is located under program files folder?

Comment: Yeah. Starts here with bad programming - editable condig files should not be in the programs folder. Goes on with the program seemingly not checking the 32 bit folder ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think for 64 bit machines the path would be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\..`

Comment: Thank you for your kind consideration..

My windows service installed using a setup and deployment project and also specified the target path property of the setup project  as 64.Then the project installed to the normal C:\Program Files\..folder instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\...

Comment: Then you might want to change the code to check the OS version and then use the appropriate path for installation?

Comment: actually error comes when i try to save or update the config file.when i copied a config file that contains some values into the application folder it could read from that particular config file but problem arise when i try to update particular file.

Comment: That should be because the config file is locked by some other process. You might want to check for other processes that use the config.